# How can I assign value on contour line in R using plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly, contour

I am using ***plot_ly*** in R Studio to plot a contour graph. I would like the contours lines to display their values directly on the graph (something like the image here : http://www.cyber-wit.com/onlineHelp/Images/contour.png). I do not know how to achieve this.
Here is my code :

```
plot_ly(width = 600, height = 600,
      type = 'contour',
      z=Matrix_Contour,
)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need `showlabels = TRUE`:

```
plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "contour", contours = list(showlabels = TRUE))
```

[image]